# how to create a fade in / fade out animation that can stopped in the middle, without jumping to end of animation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

I need to fade in and out an image, and in some cases I need to stop the animation, and reverse it. for example: an image is starting to fade-in from alpha 0 to 1, then at 0.4, because of some user input, I need to fade it out, from 0.4 to 0;

I tried using animateWithDuration and stopAllAnimations, but the result was that the animation jumps to the target alpha ( = 1).

I thought of CADisplayLink and doing the animation frame by frame by myself, but then I read that the performance is not so good.
I tried to use CALayers and PresentationLayer, but It got complicated, and it's not working.

what's the best way to do this? can anyone help me with this with a small example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIView animateWithDuration methods create Core Animation objects on layers under the covers to make the animation work. The CAAnimation animates a presentationLayer of the view's layer. You can query the presentation layer to get the state of the animation while it is in progress.

Here's what I would suggest:

Use animateWithDuration:animations: as you are doing now.

If you need to stop the animation in mid-flight, get the view's layer's presentation layer, and capture the value of the alpha property.

Then set the view's opacity the "in-flight" value and send a removeAllAnimations message to the layer. That will have the effect of stopping the animation at it's current state.

Finally, invoke a new animateWithDuration:animations: statement with your new reverse animation.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code to fade in and out

```
-(void)fadeOut:(UIView*)viewToDissolve withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
       andWait:(NSTimeInterval)wait FadeLevel:(float) fadeLevel
{
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"Fade Out" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:wait];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    viewToDissolve.alpha = fadeLevel;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)fadeIn:(UIView*)viewToFadeIn withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
      andWait:(NSTimeInterval)wait FadeLevel:(float) fadeLevel
{
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"Fade In" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:wait];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    viewToFadeIn.alpha = fadeLevel;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Just add an extra variable onto the method which will take a float, and then set the fade in or out to whatever you want. Hope that helps!

Edit: Just changed code to show you how it should look, just tested it myself, seems to work just fine

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't help. if I call "fadeOut" during the fade-in, the fade-in just keeps going until it completes. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? and as I understand both of the methods are doing the same thing, just with different argument names, am I right?

Comment: The problem with above code I gave you, is that once it is called, the alpha is automatically set to whatever you passed in, it just slowly fades to that level. I will have a think on it, have a few more ideas but would need to test them

Comment: Yeah I saw just saw his approach, pretty nice

Answer (score 0):

To stop an animation what I did is to invoke a new UIView animation with the parameter: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState so it would override the previous animation.

So I had one method to start animations from value X to value Y. An another method to interrupt the first animation. This second method was called whenever I got the button "Pause" tapped.

When I wanted to resume animation I would just call again the start animations method with the new X and Y values from the state that the object was left on.

Code to animate my UIImageView object in block format:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 5
                      delay: 0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations: ^{

                                  self.center = destinationPosition;  

                             }
                 completion:nil];
```

Here is the stop/interrupting code:

```
UIImageView *currentPosition = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self.layer presentationLayer] frame]];

                destinationPosition.x = currentPosition.center.x;
                destinationPosition.y = currentPosition.center.y;

                [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.1
                                      delay: 0.0
                                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                                 animations: ^{

                                     self.center = destinationPosition;

                                 } completion:nil];
```

In this code I used the layer presentation method to know the last value the object had during the animation so I could start animating back from that point as the user resumed gameplay. This is because the object seemed to store the projected destination value and I had to update it with the 'at the moment' value.

Note that the stop animation code has only 0.1 for duration. So its like the new animation overwriting the initial animation from the state it was found (UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState). The value is very short so it just happens to 'stop' the animation at the place where it was.

I don't know if this is the best way though, but it worked fine for me.